Prove that the order of convergence for Inverse Quadratic Interpolation is the Tribonacci Constant
I was reading about the inverse quadratic interpolation (IQI) method, where we take the 2nd degree Lagrange interpolation polynomial on $f^{-1}(y)$ and let $f^{-1}(0) \approx x_{n+1}$ to get (where $f_k = f(x_k)$):
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{f_{n-1}f_n}{(f_{n-2}-f_{n-1})(f_{n-2}-f_n)}x_{n-2} + \frac{f_{n-2}f_n}{(f_{n-1}-f_{n-2})(f_{n-1}-f_n)}x_{n-1}+\frac{f_{n-2}f_{n-1}}{(f_n-f_{n-2})(f_n-f_{n-1})}x_n$$
It is mentioned everywhere that the method has order of convergence $\approx 1.83929...$ or what is also known as the Tribonacci constant. But I can't seem to find a proof anywhere, or not even anything like an idea for a proof. The only thing I found was on wikipedia, it mentions that the proof is similar to Secant Method, which is basically the same thing but with the 1st degree Lagrange polynomial and has order of convergence $\approx 1.618...$ which is the Fibonacci constant. The proofs for Secant basically do a 2nd degree Taylor polynomial approximation of $f$ and get something like $f(x_n) \approx f'(x^*)\epsilon_n (1+M\epsilon_n)$ where $x^* = f^{-1}(0)$, $x_n = x^* + \epsilon_n$ and $M = \frac{f''(x^*)}{2f'(x^*)}$. Can we use the same for the IQI method as well? Any hints about how to follow? Would be highly appreciated.
